# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token:

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I try to update database table and this is my code:

```
public void updatefiletable(String filename, String v1, String v2){
  AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
  SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_CLOUD, v1);
  values.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_UPLOADING, v2);
  sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_FILE, values, AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME+"="+filename, null);

  sqliteDatabase.close();    
}
```

when I call my method with file_name values egal priv_priv_secondfile_2012-06-15.pdf I get that in the logcat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "15.pdf": ,
while compiling: UPDATE file_table SET file_cloud_column=?, 
file_date_upload_column=? 
WHERE file_name_column=priv_priv_secondfile_2012-06-15.pdf
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to escape the filename parameter. The punctuation in the filename is confusing SQLite. You could do it by surrounding the filename in `'single quotes'` in the string you pass in to SQLite, but it's cleaner and safer to pass it as a separate argument, like this:

```java
sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_FILE, values,
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME+"=?", new String[] {filename});
```